# Phonegap - open links in browser

Tags: iphone, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a button "visit site". Clicking on this button, the webpage should open in a new browser

I tried `window.open(LinkURL, '_system');` and some other solution but every time page is opening over app.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I have already answered a similar question. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari/17849217#17849217

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, i have tried this too. But link is opening in app only

Comment: Did you add the `inAppBrowser` plugin?

Comment: @RakeshOstwal: Which version of cordova are you using? Did u try the exact code?

Comment: @MBillau: yes, <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />

Comment: @MBillau: Yes previously i had added `inAppBrowser` but later I had removed it. I am using `cordova 3.0.4`

Comment: @NijilNair: Should i add `inAppBrowser` plugin again?

Comment: @MBillau: I m using cordova 2.7.0 and it works fine. Plugin was added by default.

Comment: @RakeshOstwal: no need to add plugin twice. see the example
var ref = window.open(encodeURI('https://www.google.co.in/'), '_system', 'location=no');

Comment: I tried doing above code but it is getting opened in app only. Can not getting what it causing it opening into web browser

Comment: I have looked into documentation. In doc var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes'); is given. But this is also not working

Comment: `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` is set to false in my config.xml I searched about this. But can not get exact answers about this. Can you please explain use of this parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solution worked for me.
I solved this issue by opening links in iFrame and providing a close link to the top left corner of the iFrame