# PhoneGap stripping anchor of external link

Tags: cordova

I'm running PhoneGap 3.0.x and using the following method to open a URL in iOS' browser:

`window.open('http://example.com/#anchor', '_system')`

The URL launches the browser fine, but it's stripping the "#anchor" from the end of the URL. Is there any way to stop this? I've tried both the system browser and in-app browser.

Comment: on which device are you testing?

Comment: @RohitTiwari I'm using a 3rd generation iPad running iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: How you have specified the whitelisting option for this external link in your config file?

Comment: see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari/17849217#17849217