# Opening safari webpage from Cordova app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I'm working on an APP that consist of HTML and CSS using the Cordova framework.
There is a button that should open a webpage. The problem is that it opens the webpage inside of the app instead of safari.

My knowledge of Objective C is extremely limited (none) so I was hoping there would be a solution using maybe Javascript.

I've looked all over the internet but couldn't find a non-Objective C solution.

The button is pretty straightforward: `<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/button.jpg" alt="website"></a>`

I thought `target="_blank"` might do something for me but that (unsurprisingly) didn't work.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari/17849217#17849217

Comment: @NijilNair I tried this but it opens the webpage inside of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem:

[Opening all URL's with Cordova childbrowser](http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/)

Only problem is that it automatically opens twitter.com because of the share button for some unknown reason. I'm guessing this is because of an api call it's performing upon being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inappbrowser plugin

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Detect click on link using javascript or jquery and use this following code

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: I tried executing the terminal commands as specified on that page but it keeps saying "command not found".

Comment: @Parrotmaster What are you using? phonegap or cordova. If you are using phonegap then you need to use phonegap instead of cordova. I'm assuming you have used CLI before to create cordova app, so you know that you don't need this `$` before command. Try `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` or `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` from inside your project folder. `cd` to your project folder and try them. This should work.

Comment: I'm using Cordova. I'll try to `cd` first.

Comment: I've tried it in all directories (xcode-projects, the project itself, the cordova folder inside the project folder) but it keeps saying "command not found".

Comment: I found out that my cordova version is 2.0.0. I'll try updating it and then use the inappbrowser plugin.

Comment: Ok I've tried updating it but it's not working out. I can't find a download for the newest version `3.5.0` and I'm failing at installing `3.4.0`. Is there any solution to my problem that works for `2.0.0`?