# Cordova won't start Safari, shows website in app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, safari, phonegap-plugins

It's all in the title.

I Tried EVERY possible way. I tried the InAppBrowser plugin, but whatever I do. It always opens in my app instead of in Safari. There is nothing wrong with this code I think?

```
window.open(encodeURI('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/linkylink/'+ variable.link), "_system",'location=no');
```

Also if i change location to yes. I dont see any changes (no location bar)

Comment: Why are you using encodeURI?

Comment: Make sure you have inAppBrowser installed `cordova plugin list`.  I also notice that if you are trying this on an anchor tag (for example you only want it to open in inAppBrowser on certain platforms or something) make sure you prevent the default event: `evt.preventDefault(); window.open(encodeURI($(this).attr('href')), '_system');`

Comment: @ceejayoz why shouldn't I?

Comment: @laughingpine The inappBrowser is installed. I do this in straight javascript(after taking a picture, open url). Don't have anchor tags. I want to do this on every platform (on android it works fine)

Comment: Not sure it is related, but try to set `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `No` in `cordova.plist`. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin wasn't loaded correctly. Reinstalled plugin and it works :)