# Open an external link in Safari (cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, browser

I am trying to open an external url link in my app which is a cordova app.  Right now its presents an in app browser using modal view but it has NO back button or close button.  The user essentially gets stuck when they click an external link.  For instance, when someone clicks this link, enclosed in "Visit Website", an in app browser shows up, the website shows up fine, BUT there is no way to navigate back to the app, or close the in app browser.  How do I go about fixing this?

```
<a href="http://www.sdtaproom.com/" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
```

I saw that there is a solution, window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "_system");, but I don't know how to implement it in the href code.

ANSWER (Edited): Add this code in the script tag in the head.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[target="_system"],a[target="_blank"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    window.open(url,"_system");
  });
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to use javascript to pick all the links, and then pick the href and use it in the window.open function

Comment: can you please give an example in code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can embed javascript code in the `href` attribute. This should do the trick:

```
<a href="javascript: window.open('http://www.sdtaproom.com/', '_system'); return false;">Visit Website</a>
```

You will also have to install the [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) plugin (don't be fooled by its name).

Comment: Too bad - it is working in one of our apps. We also have installed the [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) plugin. (Don't be fooled by its name.) You might want to check if that makes a difference.

Comment: Didnt work... Hmm.  what version of cordova are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.5.0

Comment: i figured it out.  Installed the plugin, added the code in my edited question to the script tag in the header, and worked.  Thank you.

Comment: @Glorfindel I also found it necessary to add the InAppBrowser plugin, can you update your answer?

Comment: This no longer works on iOS 14. @phemt.latd's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

as you can see [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240429/1636209) all the solution in hybrid context aren't applicable on iOS and cordova/phonegap newer versions.

For this reason i suggest to use a native plugin, try this:

https://github.com/PaoloMessina/OpenUrlExt

this plugin use this code for Android:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(<my_url>, {openExternal : true});
```

and a native Objective-C solution for iOS:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<my_url>]];
```

This plugin is installable with plugman:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/PaoloMessina/OpenUrlExt
```

And really simple to use as specified in the github README

Comment: Sorted my issue using Cordova 12, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also bear in mind that if you have **whitelisted** the linked domain using the `allow-navigation` directive from `config.xml`, the `window.open(url, '_system')` solution will not work. (But you may want use some links to navigation and some others as external link).

In this case, you could use some link shortener service like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) and link to that url instead of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem with Cordova 11. I don't know if/how it is related to this specific version, but my solution, without `window.open` was a careful configuration of the two `config.xml` settings:

All links that are supposed to open in an external Safari, and not to replace the WebView,

- need `allow-intent`
- must not have `allow-navigation`

In my case it was *all links*, so:

```xml
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<!-- NOT allow-navigation="http…*" -->
```

But I also needed Youtube iframe embeds, so I added

```
<allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*" />
```

It took me a while to understand

- `intent` ≈ open in external app (this includes Safari)
- `navigation` ≈ open in WebView root or an iframe

(this might be not 100% correct. I'm mostly writing this down for future me...)

Which helped me understand this note in the [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/allowlist/#intent-allow-list):

> Note: `allow-navigation` takes precedence over `allow-intent`. Allowing navigation to all URLs with `<allow-navigation href="*" />` for example has the side effect of "capturing" all intents, so the webview navigates to them instead of triggering e.g. external apps.

Comment: ...essentially the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152065/629238) to a (near?) duplicate question