# Open webpage in an external browser from Ipad phonegap application

Tags: ipad, html, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phonegap: open an external link in Safari not the app's UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746260/phonegap-open-an-external-link-in-safari-not-the-apps-uiwebview)

I have made an HTML5 application for my Ipad. this is made native with phonegap.
On my application, I have som external links to web pages.
However when I open these links, the external web-page is opened in my application, and since my Ipad doesn't have a 'back-button', there is no way to go back to my application. Even when I close the application, and then open it again, the external web-page is opened.

I have tried to solve the problem with a childbrowser, but I get the same problem with that.
Here is the code I used:

```
openChildBrowser('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapis_lazuli',{ showLocationBar: true });">text here</a>
```

and:

```
<a onclick= "window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapis_lazuli',{showLocationBar: true});">text here</a>
```

and I have ofcourse tried regular a href.
Do anyone have a solution to my problem?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Sorry do you mean if you close the application while the ChildBrowser is opened that when the app is re-opened the childbrowser is still displayed?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. I can't manage to return from the external web-page and back to my own application because the external web-page is opened in the same window, instead of in an browser (or some other solution) :)

Comment: @SimonMacDonald: You do not know a solution on how to open the external webpages external instead of inside the application? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I solved it by adding target="_blank" inside the a-tag like this.

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapis_lazuli" target="_blank">text here</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great, I think this will work. You are good at this Tinna... :p

Comment: This works for me on Android in 2017. I don't know if iOS will work though until I try it...