# Phonegap iPhone target link issue

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, target

Following this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9748173/356042)

I'm using **cordova 2.0**.

I need to open in safari window some specific links. But at the same time I need to **load external ads in the same WebView**. So I'm using this conf:

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES
ExternalHosts = ['*']
```

Setting that I'm not having any problems with *ads/GA/et*. However, for links I've tried using target=_blank as many posts said but setting `ExternalHosts = ['*']` seems to   break the `target=_blank` functionality.

### example

```
<a href='external.com' target=_blank> open in Safari</a>
<a href='internal.com' > open in WebView</a>
```

### Question:

It is possible to force a link target to be opended into safari window using `ExternalHosts = ['*']` and `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES`  ??

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might work.
I'm running 2.1 an running into
the same problem.

I'm still looking for a more
eligent solution.
http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2012/05/22/opening-links-in-phonegap-apps-in-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 0):

Just catch all links in your javascript that have `target="_blank"`, and pass them to window.open with the '_system' param. This will work on both iOS and Android.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(ev) {
  var url;

  ev.preventDefault();
  url = $(this).attr('href');
  window.open(url, '_system');
});
```