# iPad fullscreen mode - no escape found

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, fullscreen

I have a web App which has links to other web pages. When a user taps one of these links while the app is running from full screen mode the new page opens in full screen as well and so there is no means of navigating back to the web App. Has anyone found a method for escaping full screen mode on the iPad once a web App has been launched from a home screen icon ?

Comment: By "full screen mode" do you mean displaying a web page in Safari?  And otherwise you are displaying a page in a web view in your own app?

Comment: This is not a native iOS app - but a web app operating from fullscreen mode as a result of saving the icon to the home screen. While experimenting with displaying the target URL inside a div, iFrame clicking on links on the iframe web page does take you out of full screen mode....

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting with javascript, like:

```
document.location='';
```

We actually consider this a bug, but as always there are those who would see this as a feature :)

Comment: It would be a great feature if there were a means of navigating back to the web app !

Answer (score 0):

If the page your going to is supposed to be in the app, then this solves your problem.

[How can I open an external link in Safari not the app's UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746260/phonegap-open-an-external-link-in-safari-not-the-apps-uiwebview)

If the page is any page on the internet, then the answer is pretty much no.

Once you leave the app, there is no way back, except for the user clicking back on your app.

It is not simple to force the ipad to stay in your app.   Some suggested methods:

1. Create your own web view in your app.  If your using phone gap, or another framework, you would have to create a plug in to do this.  You would then show the loaded pages on that web view, this is similar to how ads are shown & stay in the app.
2. Parse and replace all the links on the loaded page with custom events, and use a server to return the content, instead of loading it directly via the web.

Both are very complex, and have issues, like you cant have white lists if you let them browse outside specific domains.

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment I did experiment with placing an iFrame inside a div which pops up. Very clunky presentation as the web pages typically require scrolling inside the iframe. Personally I would be ok with it just exiting full screen when a url is clicked...Would be great if we could toggle full screen using Javascript.....

Comment: Yea, a lot of people are asking for this feature.

Comment: What is interesting is that using standard <a href= works to open a new window in Safari from a web App in fullscreen however using any alternative like window.open or this.location does not behave the same and opens in fullScreen....