# Force any link in Google Maps API to open in iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I am using Google Maps API V3 in my PhoneGap app using jQuery Mobile

Problem is when I click on ANY links inside the map view, including the Google logo and Google terms and conditions link the link takes over the app.

How can I force all links to open into iPhone Safari.

Comment: You can see that :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746260/how-can-i-open-an-external-link-in-safari-not-the-apps-uiwebview