# How can I open external links in safari.app from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, safari

I want to request external links in safari.app. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried all codes from [How can I open an external link in Safari not the app's UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746260/how-can-i-open-an-external-link-in-safari-not-the-apps-uiwebview) but they all doesn't work in my code.

Have you any ideas? Where is my mistake? Thank you for help!

Here's my Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.iPhoneWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]]];
    [self.iPadWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]]];

}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    //  open External Links (not beginning with http://www.example.com in Safari.app
    if (
        (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) &&
        ( ![[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://www.example.com"])
        ) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    //open Internal links in uiwebview
    return YES;
}


- (void)displayActivityControllerWithDataObject:(id)obj {
    UIActivityViewController* vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                    initWithActivityItems:@[obj] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // starting the load, show the activity indicator in the status bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // finished loading, hide the activity indicator in the status bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // load error, hide the activity indicator in the status bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    // report the error inside the webview
    NSString* errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<html><center><font size=+5 color='red'>Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten<br>%@</font></center></html>",
                             error.localizedDescription];
    [self.iPhoneWebView loadHTMLString:errorString baseURL:nil];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 7):

Set the delegate of your webview to self, dont forget !

This works for me :

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```